# UserManager.FindAsync does not work

Tags: asp.net, azure, asp.net-identity

Hi my code is working perfectly fine on my own machine and another VM. Now, i have deployed it on Azure VM (not by publishing but by simply copying and creating a virtual directory). Now when i try to login

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["SchoolCode"] = model.SchoolCode;
                logger.Debug("assigning school code [" + model.SchoolCode + "] to session, password: " + model.Password);

                var user = await UserManager.FindAsync(model.Username, model.Password);

                logger.Debug("is school code valid: ");

                if (user != null && isSchoolCodeValid(model.SchoolCode))
                {
                    await SignInAsync(user, model.RememberMe);
                    return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
                }
                else if(user == null)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid username or password.");
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid School Code.");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                logger.Error(e.Message);
            }

        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

my log file only shows the first log and then nothing happens

> 2017-09-27 09:41:56,915 [16] DEBUG - assigning school code [sc002] to
>   session

I am also using a different port (93) on iis because it gave me the error that two sites cannot run simultaneously on the same port[image]

Comment: UPDATE: i guess port did not matter as now i have changed it back to 80

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, my issue was entirely different from what i thought it was.

Firstly, i had increased the logging but my iis was picking the cached version which was why i was unable to see the logs. After i was able to see the Error in logs, it said

> String was not recognized as a valid Boolean

It took me quiet a while to realize this error was coming due to database **aspnetusers** table. I changed **EmailConfirmed** from **0** to **False** and that fixed the issue!